# How to return all leaves in a recursive tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, decision-tree

I'm trying to create a function that will return all the leaves in my recursive tree. I saw many other posts about it but I couldn't modify it to my own code. I am trying to make like a decision tree. This is my code:

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, data, positive_child=None, negative_child=None):
    self.data = data
    self.positive_child = positive_child
    self.negative_child = negative_child
    self.children_list = []

class Decision:
    def __init__(self, root: Node):
        self.root = root
        self.current = root

    def collect_leaves(self, node, leafs):
        if node is not None:
            if len(node.children_list) == 0:
                leafs.append(node.data)
            for n in node.children_list:
                self.collect_leaves(n, leafs)

    def return_all_leaves(self):
        leafs = []
        self.collect_leaves(self.root, leafs)
        return leafs
```

from some reason it returns only the root, and not the leaves..

For example:

```
flu_leaf2 = Node("influenza", None, None)
cold_leaf2 = Node("cold", None, None)
hard_leaf2 = Node("hard influenza", None, None)
headache_node2 = Node("headache", hard_leaf2, flu_leaf2)
inner_vertex2 = Node("fever", headache_node2, cold_leaf2)
healthy_leaf2 = Node("healthy", None, None)
root2 = Node("cough", inner_vertex2, healthy_leaf2)
diagnoser2 = Diagnoser(root2)
```

`diagnoser2.return_all_leaves(self)` is supposed to return:

```
['hard influenza', 'influenza','cold','healthy']
```

Comment: First thing to notice is you're collecting the node and not its data, is that what you mean to do? `leafs.append(node)` and not `leafs.append(node.data)`

Comment: hmm thats true, but still after I am changing this its only append the root and not the leaves(and no, I mean node.data)

Comment: I think we need to see `_collect_leaf_nodes`

Comment: collect leaves is_collect_leaf_nodes, I just changed the name of the functions. Again,edited. Sorry for the misunderstood.

Comment: Where do you ever put anything into `children_list`?

Comment: Oh. Probably this is the problem. How can I append every Node to the list?

Comment: adding a `__str__` method to node will help you

Comment: like this?:    def __str__(self):
         self.children_list = []
         self.children_list.append(self.data)   because its give me an error ("'Node' object has no attribute 'children_list'"  here - if len(node.children_list) == 0:  )

Comment: I added an example above

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need the `children_list`. It seems like just an extra thing to maintain. I think it should be enough to determine if the node has a `positive_child` or a `negative_child`.

Note the addition of the `__str__` method to Node to show something nice when printing...

Take a look at:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, positive_child=None, negative_child=None):
        self.data = data
        self.positive_child = positive_child
        self.negative_child = negative_child

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.data

class Decision:
    def __init__(self, root: Node):
        self.root = root

    def collect_leaves(self, node):
        ## ---------------------------
        ## This node has no children. It is a leaf
        ## ---------------------------
        if not node.positive_child and not node.negative_child:
            return [node]
        ## ---------------------------

        ## ---------------------------
        ## Recursively collect the leaves of children
        ## ---------------------------
        leaves = []
        if node.positive_child:
            leaves.extend(self.collect_leaves(node.positive_child))
        if node.negative_child:
            leaves.extend(self.collect_leaves(node.negative_child))
        return leaves
        ## ---------------------------

    def return_all_leaves(self):
        return self.collect_leaves(self.root)

my_decsion = Decision(
    Node(
        "root",
        Node("root_a", None, None),
        Node(
            "root_b",
            Node("root_b_1", None),
            Node("root_b_2", None),
        ),
    )
)

for node in my_decsion.return_all_leaves():
    print(node)
```

That should give you:

```
root_a
root_b_1
root_b_2
```

Note though that recursion in python is a little limited and you might want to look at an implementation that is not based on it.

If you wanted a version of `return_all_leaves()` that was not based on recursion, you might try:

```
    def return_all_leaves2(self):
        leaves = []
        todo = [self.root]
        while todo:
            this_node = todo.pop(0)

            ## ---------------------------
            ## This node was None... I think this is cleaner than testing
            ## parent_node.positive_child and parent_node.negative_child
            ## ---------------------------
            if not this_node:
                continue
            ## ---------------------------

            ## ---------------------------
            ## This node has no children. It is a leaf
            ## ---------------------------
            if not this_node.positive_child and not this_node.negative_child:
                leaves.append(this_node)
                continue
            ## ---------------------------

            ## ---------------------------
            ## add the leaves of children to future work
            ## ---------------------------
            todo.append(this_node.positive_child)
            todo.append(this_node.negative_child)
            ## ---------------------------

        return leaves
```

If we test with your data:

```
my_decsion2 = Decision(
    Node(
        "cough",
        Node(
            "fever",
            Node(
                "headache",
                Node("hard influenza", None, None),
                Node("influenza", None, None)
            ),
            Node("cold", None, None)
        ),
        Node("healthy", None, None)
    )
)

for node in my_decsion2.return_all_leaves():
    print(node)
```

This code prints:

```
hard influenza
influenza
cold
healthy
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much:) . Its returned me only their location, I mean this:                            [<__main__.Node object at 0x000001B63BF63A60>, <__main__.Node object at 0x000001B63BF63B20>, <__main__.Node object at 0x000001B63BF63AC0>, <__main__.Node object at 0x000001B63BF63940>]                                                                         But the len is good. its supposed to return 4 items,but when I am trying to write node.positive_child.data,it gives me an error ('str' object has no attribute 'positive_child')

Comment: Did you see I implemented the `__str__` method in `Node`? That allows you to do `print(some_node)` in a nice way rather than seeing what you see.

Comment: hmm yes, I wrote it as you said. You are welcome to try if you want to see, I wrote the exact same example that I am using :) Also the second one the exact same problem. Again, much appreciation! You help is not obvious

Comment: Take a look at the code I posted. It has some changes to both your classes. also, your example uses a class `Diagnoser` that I think might be something you did not post and should be `Decision` in the context of this question. With the test data you posted, my this code prints the 4 data names

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much!Its less important, but do you know why the return value of the function is still [<__main__.Node object at 0x000001B63BF63A60>, <__main__.Node object at 0x000001B63BF63B20>, <__main__.Node object at 0x000001B63BF63AC0>, <__main__.Node object at 0x000001B63BF63940>] ?

Comment: It is returning Nodes. and you you want something nicer to look at you need to implement `__repr__` and `__str__` on Node :-)